# Office Word vba: how to insert a column after a merged cell? some cells outside table

Tags: vba, ms-word

When I use Office Word 2019 VBA to insert a column on the right side of table, contain some merge cell.

I want to get result shown in EX2, but run below code, the result EX3 has appeared, some cell go out tables;
my code is：

```
 Sub test()

     Dim p As Long

     Dim tb As Table

     Set tb = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)

     tb.Cell(1, 1).Select

     p = Selection.Information(wdMaximumNumberOfColumns)

     tb.Cell(1, p).Select

     Selection.InsertColumnsRight

End Sub
```

How to show ex2, result ?,thanks.
EX1：[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uR1s.png
EX2：
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxfs5.png
EX3：
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zrf76.png

Answer (score 0):

```
I think out it， code is：

 Sub Atest()
 Dim t As Table, r As Long, p As Long, cw As Single
 Set t = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
 t.Cell(1, 1).Select                                     'select table fisrt cell
 p = Selection.Information(wdMaximumNumberOfColumns)    'get current  column Count
 t.Cell(1, p).Select                                     'select table fisrt rows,last cell
 cw = t.Cell(1, p).Width                                ' first row,last cell width
 q = Selection.Information(wdMaximumNumberOfRows)          ''get current row Count
For r = 1 To q
  t.Cell(r, 1).Select
  p = Selection.Information(wdMaximumNumberOfColumns)       ' some row include merge cell ,so every rows need get it column count
  t.Cell(r, p).Select
  Selection.Next(Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1).Select              'move cursor outside of every row's last cell
  Selection.InsertCells (0)                                   'so,at this time ,inert a cell of last cell right side,
  t.Cell(r, p + 1).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=cw, RulerStyle:=3     '0 means:wdInsertCellsShiftRight
Next r                                                         ' every insert cell set  a same column width
```